# How do I create a column based on values of another using dplyr without having to write down every value?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there any way of doing this more efficiently? I want to create a column of the type of item. Each participant has a different number of items, so it's really tricky. Here is a toy example of my data

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), condition = c("high", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
"high", "high", "high", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", 
"medium", "medium", "medium", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", 
"medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium", "medium"
), item = c("abcde", "bcdef", "cdefgh", "defgh", "efghi", "fghijk", 
"ghijkl", "hijklm", "1234", "2345", "3456", "4567", "5678", "6789", 
"7890", "onion", "celery", "tomato", "carrot", "green bean", 
"lettuce", "garlic", "abcde", "bcdef", "cdefgh", "defgh", "efghi", 
"fghijk", "ghijkl", "hijklm", "onion", "celery", "tomato", "carrot", 
"green bean", "lettuce", "garlic", "1234", "2345", "3456", "4567", 
"5678", "6789", "7890")), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I have done so far but it's a nightmare because I have more than a hundred different items:

```
df$subs <- 0
df$subs[df$item=="abcde"] <- "A"
df$subs[df$item=="bcdef"] <- "A"
df$subs[df$item=="cdefg"] <- "A"
df$subs[df$item=="defgh"] <- "A"
df$subs[df$item=="efghi"] <- "A"

df$subs[df$item=="12345"] <- "B"
df$subs[df$item=="23456"] <- "B"
df$subs[df$item=="34567"] <- "B"
df$subs[df$item=="45678"] <- "B"
df$subs[df$item=="56789"] <- "B"

df$subs[df$item=="onion"] <- "C"
df$subs[df$item=="celery"] <- "C"
df$subs[df$item=="tomato"] <- "C"
df$subs[df$item=="carrot"] <- "C"
df$subs[df$item=="green bean"] <- "C"
```

Is there a faster way of doing this with tidyverse?

Comment: This doesn't use tidyverse, and it's still probably not an optimal solution, but you could do something like `x <- c("abcde", "bcdef", "cdefg", "defgh", "efghi")` followed by `df$subs[df$item %in% x] <- "A"`.  It would at least save you having to write a line for each value you're trying to match.

Comment: If there is no explicit formula for the item-LETTER mappings, it's hard to see how you can do the assignments with code.  If you have to do the assignments by hand it may be easier to do it in Excel and then import the completed data frame to R.  For the LETTERS column in Excel you could use the Data Validation function and create a List of the allowed values.  That would provide a selection drop-down for each cell to make the inputting easier.  Also each time you finish a LETTER mapping you could sort the columns to keep all the cells yet to be assigned contiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to use regex to simplify this. You could use the tidyverse, but it's not absoulately necessary. Here's a tidyverse example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(subs = case_when(
    str_detect(item, "[a-m]{5}") ~ "A",
    str_detect(item, pattern = "\\d+") ~ "B",
                          TRUE ~ "C"))
```

The key here is that the regex patterns you choose need to be precise for your real data. I think this version works for the simple example you've included. Also, just to note that the `dput` reprex is different to the data presented - hence my choice to use `[a-m]` in the first regex pattern.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, and it works like magic, but I have no idea how to use regex or how to find a code for it. I found a website that might shed some light, but for example the \\d+ does not make sense to me. Any suggestion of how to google it? "Regex code" did not work.

Comment: Glad I could help. `\\d+` recognises one or more digits. Regex can be quite challenging to pick up I'm sorry to say. Here's the Rstudio cheatsheet for reference - https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf - also this site, https://regexr.com/, allows you to try out the concepts.